# blender 2.91.2 Viewport displays only gray in preview or rendered shading

Tags: rendering, objects

I just installed blender 2.91.2 and whenever I switch to wireframe view it displays only the outer frame while the material preview or  render view shows nothing but gray , whether it's new project or old from the previous version it's the same
[image]